# "missing FROM-clause entry for table" error for a rails table query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to use an `inner join` a view and a table using the following query

```
SELECT 
   AcId, AcName, PldepPer, RepId, CustCatg, HardCode, BlockCust, CrPeriod, CrLimit, 
   BillLimit, Mode, PNotes, gtab82.memno 
FROM
   VCustomer 
INNER JOIN   
   vcustomer AS v1 ON gtab82.memacid = v1.acid 
WHERE (AcGrCode = '204' OR CreDebt = 'True') 
AND Masked = 'false'
ORDER BY AcName
```

and the error is

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "gtab82"
```

Comment: Err, yeah. You reference `gtab82` in your `SELECT` and `ON` clause yet haven't specified it in either `FROM` or `JOIN`. You also appear to be attempting to join `vcustomer` to itself

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   AcId, AcName, PldepPer, RepId, CustCatg, HardCode, BlockCust, CrPeriod, CrLimit, 
   BillLimit, Mode, PNotes, gtab82.memno 
FROM
   VCustomer AS v1
INNER JOIN   
   gtab82 ON gtab82.memacid = v1.AcId 
WHERE (AcGrCode = '204' OR CreDebt = 'True') 
AND Masked = 'false'
ORDER BY AcName
```

You typically only use an alias for a table name when you need to prefix a column with the table name due to duplicate column names in the joined tables and the table name is long or when the table is joined to itself. In your case you use an alias for `VCustomer` but only use it in the `ON` clause for uncertain reasons. You may want to review that aspect of your code.

Comment: This was actually useful to me because I had a hardcoded query in my code behind that was selecting from a view in the database, so the issue with the alias was obfuscated.

Comment: I can't see how this answers the question, other than a very hard-to-notice correction of the query (changing "INNER JOIN vcustomer" to "INNER JOIN gtab82").

Answer (score 21):

Because that gtab82 table isn't in your FROM or JOIN clause. You refer gtab82 table in these cases: gtab82.memno and gtab82.memacid