# Postgres: missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, syntax-error

I'm trying to execute a join query for 4 tables on postgres.

Table names:

- `scenarios_scenario`
- `payments_invoice`
- `payments_payment`
- `payments_action`

(all those weird names are generated by django -)))

Relations:

- `scenarios_scenario` [has many] `payments_action`s
- `payments_action` [has one] `payments_invoice`
- `payments_action` [has one] `payments_payment`

Below one is a working query,

```sql
SELECT payments_invoice.*,
  (payments_payment.to_be_paid - payments_payment.paid) as remaining, \
  payments_action.identificator
FROM payments_invoice
JOIN payments_payment
  ON payments_invoice.action_id = payments_payment.action_id
  AND payments_payment.full_payment=2
JOIN payments_action
  ON payments_invoice.action_id = payments_action.id
  AND payments_action.identificator = %s
```

I just want to retrieve a related field from another table and wrote another query like

```sql
SELECT 
  scenarios_scenario.title, payments_invoice.*, \
  (payments_payment.to_be_paid - payments_payment.paid) as remaining, \
  payments_action.identificator, payments_action.scenario_id 
FROM payments_invoice 
JOIN scenarios_scenario 
  ON scenarios_scenario.id = payments_action.scenario_id
JOIN payments_payment 
  ON payments_invoice.action_id = payments_payment.action_id 
  AND payments_payment.full_payment=2 
JOIN payments_action 
  ON payments_invoice.action_id = payments_action.id 
  AND payments_action.identificator = 'EEE45667';
```

but facing with this error -

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "payments_action"
LINE 2: ...IN  scenarios_scenario ON scenarios_scenario.id = payments_a...
                                                             ^
```

Looked across SO for similar questions like this (["missing FROM-clause entry for table" error for a rails table query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557563/missing-from-clause-entry-for-table)) but weren't able to find a way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post your python code, please?

Comment: i have no problem with python. will use `django.db.connection` as soon as i will be able to fix this query -))

Comment: Have you tried moving your first `JOIN` to the bottom? You try to join `scenarios_scenario` before you joined `payments_action`.

Comment: thanks @Dmitriy -)) moved to bottom and this worked

Comment: @marmeladze while there is nothing wrong with SQL, the ORM in django does a lot of this for you.

Comment: @hd1 ofcourse, but i don't feel comfortable with django's orm, i think it is designed for making things more difficult -))

Comment: No, it's really not -- if you post your models, I'll be happy to rewrite your query, if you post your model classes.

Comment: here you are - https://gist.github.com/marmeladze/87075548b0fb8de1082e95b112603803

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your first join 'payments_action' is not a known relation. Reorder your joins in a way that a new join only uses already 'defined' relations.

Here is a fiddle, demonstrating the issue:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ed147/5

Answer (score 7):

Change the code so that you join each table before calling a column from it in another join.  The postgres query planner reads the joins sequentially so that in your code table `scenarios_scenario` is being joined to table `payments_invoice` and is looking for a match with `payments_action`, but the query planner doesn't know what `payments_action` is yet.  The new code should be:

```
SELECT 
    scenarios_scenario.title, payments_invoice.*, \
    (payments_payment.to_be_paid - payments_payment.paid) as remaining, \
    payments_action.identificator, payments_action.scenario_id 
FROM payments_invoice 
JOIN payments_action 
ON (
    payments_invoice.action_id = payments_action.id 
    AND payments_action.identificator = 'EEE45667'    
)
JOIN scenarios_scenario 
ON (
    scenarios_scenario.id = payments_action.scenario_id
)
JOIN payments_payment 
ON (
    payments_invoice.action_id = payments_payment.action_id 
    AND payments_payment.full_payment=2 
);
```

Answer (score 5):

You are joining to table [scenarios_scenario] using a field from [payments_action].

The joins must be in sequence, i.e. you cannot reference fields from a table with the ON statement unless their tables precede the statement.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error message but related to alias naming issue.
For example the following sql query does not work and throws the same error `missing FROM-clause entry for table`:

```
select aDr.address_line1 from core_addresses as "aDr"
```

If you are using Capital letters in alias names, you must use double quotes or use `snake_case` instead.
The following queries fix the issue:

```
select "aDr".address_line1 from core_addresses as "aDr" // added quotes
select a_dr.address_line1 from core_addresses as "a_dr" // snake case
```

Comment: This is such an important information, I did not knew that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "my"

When I didn't use a [current_setting()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET) to use a custom option as shown below:

```sql
SELECT my.num;
```

So, I used `current_setting()` as shown below, then I could use the custom option without error:

```sql
SELECT current_setting('my.num');
```